# How to get all fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

How to get all field names (not values) under _source using elastic4s ? I want a list of all mapped fields .
I tried doing something like:

```
search in indexName / indexType sourceInclude "_source" limit q.limit aggregations(
                aggregation terms "agg0" field "_field_names"  size 0

              )
```

or even

```
 search in indexName / indexType sourceInclude "_source" sourceExclude ("_all", "_type",
                "_uid", "_version", "_index", "_score", "_id")  limit q.limit aggregations(
                aggregation terms "agg0" field "_field_names"  size 0

              )
```

but that didn't do it . I got all metadata fields and not just those under _source

```
"aggregations" : {
    "agg0" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "_all",
        "doc_count" : 1500
      }, {
        "key" : "_source",
        "doc_count" : 1500
      }, {
        "key" : "_type",
        "doc_count" : 1500
      }, {
        "key" : "_uid",
        "doc_count" : 1500
      }, {
        "key" : "_version",
        "doc_count" : 1500
      }
.. more fields
```

**==== Update ===**

I found this way :

```
val map = getMapping indexName /indexType}
val y = map.get("properties").asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, _]]
y.keys.toList
```

is there a better way for getting the same result ?

Comment: Do you want a list of fields for each document or is it the same for the whole type? You can use `getMapping(<index> / <type>)` if it is per type

Comment: thanks, it looks like a good approach. checkout my update

Answer (score 1):

use Get Mapping API

```
GET /index/_mapping
GET /index/_mapping/type
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

OR use Cluster API

```
GET /_cluster/state
```

FIELD LIST :

```
json -> metadata -> indices -> your_index -> mapping
```